# Meteor subscription in React using a passed prop errors if page is refreshed

Tags: meteor-react

Im using React with Meteor. In my top level component I have my main subscriptions:

```
export default withTracker(() => {
    let groupsSub = Meteor.subscribe('groups');
    let eventsSub = Meteor.subscribe('events');
    let userSub = Meteor.subscribe('currentUser');
    return {
        groups: Groups.find({}).fetch(),
        events: Events.find({}).fetch(),
        user: Meteor.user() || false,
    };
})(App);
```

The subscription data is passed as props to a child component which is on a new page (using React Router 4).

This is working so far. On the child page I also need to get an ID from the props and use it as part of an additional subscription called CommentsApiSub:

```
export default withTracker(props => {
    const attachedTo = props.group[0]._id;
    let CommentsApiSub = Meteor.subscribe('comments', { attachedTo });
    return {
        comments: CommentsApi.find({}).fetch(),
    };
})(Child);
```

And this is the CommentsApi publication:

```
Meteor.publish('comments', function({ attachedTo }) {
    console.log(attachedTo);
    return CommentsApi.find(
        { attachedTo },
        { fields: { date: 1, body: 1, user: 1 } },
    );
});
```

If I navigate to the page it works fine, but if I refresh the page I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

I know this is because props.group hasnt loaded but im not sure how to delay calling my comments subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if if Meteor subscription is ready before attempting to load your components. *Meteor.subscribe()* returns a *subscription handle*, which contains a reactive data source called **ready()**. As an example by using your code;

```
export default withTracker(() => {
    const groupsSub = Meteor.subscribe('groups');
    // Remaining of the code here 
    return {
        loading: !groupsSub.ready()
        groups: Groups.find({}).fetch(),
        // Other props 
    };
})(App);
```

And in your *render()* method, you can use that *loading* prop to check if the subscription ready;

```
render () {
        const { loading } = this.props;
        if (loading) {
            return (
                <h2>Loading Page ...</h2>
            );
        }
       // Remaining of the code
}
```

You can refer to the official Meteor documentation [here](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#readiness).